# haxe/flash: Camera.getCamera() by name returns null

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, camera, haxe

Preliminary note: I use haxe for writing and compiling the code.

The case is as follows: I have up to four cameras on the same machine and I need to capture them individually. flash.media.Camera.getCamera() takes a name and I guess it's the name of the camera I want to target. I take the names from the flash.media.Camera.names Array.

Is it really possible to capture the targeted camera or will I only always get the system default? flash.media.Camera.names lists all the attached cameras so I really hope I can target them individually.

Below is the code in question.

```
class Capture {
    static function main(){

        var mc:flash.display.MovieClip = flash.Lib.current;
        var i:Int = 0;

        trace(flash.media.Camera.names);

        for(camera in flash.media.Camera.names){

            trace(camera);
            trace(Type.typeof(camera));

            var xpos = 490;
            var ypos = 10;

            var rawvideo:flash.media.Video = new flash.media.Video(480, 360);
            var cam:flash.media.Camera = flash.media.Camera.getCamera(camera);

            trace(cam);

            cam.setMode(640, 480, 30);
            cam.setQuality(0, 100);

            rawvideo.attachCamera(cam);
            rawvideo.scaleX = -1;

            switch(i){
                case 0:
                case 1:
                    xpos += 490;
                case 2:
                    ypos += 370;
                case 3:
                    xpos += 490;
                    ypos += 370;
            }

            i++;

            rawvideo.x = xpos;
            rawvideo.y = ypos;

            if (cam != null){
                var videoContainer:flash.display.MovieClip = new flash.display.MovieClip();
                videoContainer.addChild(rawvideo);
                mc.addChild(videoContainer);
            } else {
                trace("No Camera");
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oddly enough, getCamera doesn't really take the camera name (from the names array), but a string representing the index position in the names array.  From the Camera getCamera documentation:

`To specify a value for this parameter, use the string representation of the zero-based index position within the Camera.names array. For example, to specify the third camera in the array, use Camera.getCamera("2").`

Comment: Makes kind of sense. I got a names array like [Logitech Cam,Logitech Cam,Logitech Cam #2]. So the name is not really an unique identifier. But that it has to be a string of the index, that's odd :)